# Play sound on specific sound device java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am trying to do something simple. I want to play sound on a given sound media instead of playing on the default one.

There is my last try, to iterate thought all the media and play a sound. Only the media on the default device play something. Even the default device is not working when is played directly.

```
public void testSoundPLayer() throws Exception {
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(Constants.SOUND_ALERT));

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for(int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++)
    {
        Mixer.Info info = mixerInfo[i];

        System.out.println(String.format("Name [%s] \n Description [%s]\n\n", info.getName(), info.getDescription()));
        System.out.println(info.getDescription());

        try
        {
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(info);
            clip.open(inputStream);
            clip.start();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
    }
}
```

I am open to use external librairies, or even to change the default sound card. I just want a "nice" method to play a sound (wav) on a given sound card without OS dependent method.

Comment: `Clip` is part of Java Sound, not JMF.  *"I just want a "nice" method to play a sound (wav) without OS dependent method."* You are confused. The `Clip` is it!

Comment: Effectively my last sentence is confusing. I want a nice method to play a sound on a given sound card. I edit the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a shame, I have done a huge mistake, I have not reloaded the stream. This means the seconds play doesn't work.

There is an working example.

```
public void testSoundPLayer() throws Exception {

Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
for(int i = 0; i < mixerInfo.length; i++)
{
    AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Main.class.getResourceAsStream(Constants.SOUND_ALERT));

    Mixer.Info info = mixerInfo[i];

    System.out.println(String.format("Name [%s] \n Description [%s]\n\n", info.getName(), info.getDescription()));
    System.out.println(info.getDescription());

    try
    {
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(info);
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
}
```

}

For checking if the device is an input or output use the following method :

```
// Param for playback (input) device.
Line.Info playbackLine = new Line.Info(SourceDataLine.class);
// Param for capture (output) device.
Line.Info captureLine = new Line.Info(TargetDataLine.class);


private List<Mixer.Info> filterDevices(final Line.Info supportedLine) {
    List<Mixer.Info> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    ArrayList<Mixer.Info> infos = Lists.newArrayList(AudioSystem.getMixerInfo());
    for (Mixer.Info info : infos) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        if (mixer.isLineSupported(supportedLine)) {
            result.add(info);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to use vlc for this task, but it is super with pure Java